# iText for .NET Paragraph Element overlapping its own text

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, paragraph

I'm dynamically creating PDF reports, and sometimes the content is too long and (should) span multiple pages. I'm using a Paragraph element and it's just overwriting its cell space.

[image: Just like here]

Code:

```vb
'Table SPECS
Dim tab As New PdfPTable(1)
tab.TotalWidth = 502.0F
tab.LockedWidth = True
tab.SpacingBefore = 140.0F

Dim phrase As Phrase = Nothing
Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase())
phrase = New Phrase() 
phrase.Add(New Chunk(dr("Subject").ToString() & vbLf, font))
cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT)
cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP
cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_CENTER
cell.PaddingLeft = 5.0F
cell.PaddingBottom = 2.0F
cell.PaddingTop = 0.0F
cell.Border = 0
tab.AddCell(cell)

Dim p As Paragraph = New Paragraph(dr("Contents"), font)
p.SpacingBefore = 140.0F
Dim Col As New ColumnText(writer.DirectContent)
Col.SetSimpleColumn(50, doc.Bottom + 160, 540, doc.Top - 160)
Col.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
Col.AddText(p)
cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
cell.PaddingLeft = 5.0F
cell.PaddingBottom = 2.0F
cell.PaddingTop = 0.0F
cell.Border = 0
Col.Go()
doc.Add(tab)
doc.Close()
```

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: (1) show us your code. (2) you are using the wrong value for the `leading`. (3) we can show you where your code is wrong if you show your code.

Comment: I see you both layouting text yourself (using a `new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent)`) and asking iText to layout text (using `doc.Add(tab)`). Have you made sure the text you layout does not get into the way of the text iText layouts?

Comment: @mkl Actually I just added the column in my last iteration of attempts. It was almost the same before I did.

Comment: Well, your screen dump looks like your two parts, the table and the column text, overlap. And as your code is incomplete, it cannot be used to reproduce the issue. Thus, at this stage, we can still only guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by using SpacingAfter property of itextSharp.
See the full code here:
http://agalaxycode.blogspot.in/2015/01/paragraph-overlapping-problem-in-itextSharp.html